# How to efficently manage a list of elements that can either have one of it's elements removed or swapped with it's next one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a program having two inputs (eventList, a list composed of strings that hold the type of operation and the id of the element that will undergo it, and idList, a list composed of ints, each one being the id of the element).

The two possible events are the deletion of the corresponding id, or having the id swap it's position in the idList with the following one (i.e. if the selected id is located in idList[2], it will swap value with idList[3]).

It has to pass strict tests with a set timeout and has to use dictionaries.

This is for a programmation assignment, I've alredy built this program but I can't find a way to get a decent time and pass the tester's timeouts.
I've alseo tried using lists instead of dicts, but I still can't pass some timeouts because of the time it takes to use .pop() and .index(), and I've been told the only way to pass all of them is to use dicts.

How I currently handle swaps:

```py
def overtake(dictElement, elementId):
    elementIndex = dictElement[elementId]
    overtakerId = dictSearchOvertaker(dictElement, elementIndex)
    dictElement[elementId], dictElement[overtakerId] = dictElement[overtakerId], dictElement[elementId]
    return dictElement
```

How I currently handle deletions:

```py
def eliminate(dictElement, elementId):
    #elementIndex = dictElement[elementId]
    del dictElement[elementId] 
    return dictUpdate(dictElement, elementId)
```

How i update the dictionary after an element is deleted:

```py
def dictUpdate(dictElement, elementIndex):
    listedDict = dictElement.items()
    i = 0
    for item in listedDict:
        i += 1
        if item[1] > elementIndex:
            dictElement[item[0]] -= 1
    return dictElement
```

I'm expected to handle a list of 200k elements where every element gets deleted one by one in 1.5 seconds, but it takes me more than 5 minutes, and even longer for a test where I get an idList with 1500 elements and every elements gets swapped with the following one untill in the end idList is reversed .

Comment: Swapping elements until the list is reversed is an O(n^2) operation. (you are basically bubble sorting an ordered list).   Doing this on a 200k long list would take a long, long time.

Comment: I can't think of other ways to handle this, I can't call the next dict key directly like you can do with elements in a list, how could I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that strikes me about this problem is that you're given a single list of operations and expected to return the result of doing all of them.  That means you don't necessarily need to do them all one by one, and can instead do operations in a single batch that would otherwise be individually time-consuming.

Swapping two items is O(1) as long as you already know where they are.  That's where a dict would come in -- a dict can help you associate one piece of information with another in such a way that you can find it in O(1) time.  In this case, you want a way to find the index of an item given its id.

Deleting an item from the middle of a Python list is O(N), even if you already know its index, because internally it's an array and you need to shift everything over to take up the empty space every time you delete something that's not at the end.  A naive solution is going to therefore be O(K*N), which is probably the thing the assignment is trying to get you to avoid.  But nothing in the problem requires that you actually delete each item from the list one by one, just that the final result you return does not contain those items.

So, my approach would be:

- Build a dict of `id -> index`.  (This is just a single O(n) iteration over the list.)
- Create an empty set to track deletions.
- For each operation:

  - If it's a swap:

    - If the id is in your set, raise an exception.
    - Use your dict to find the indices of the two ids.
    - Swap the two items in the list.
    - Update your dict so it continues to match the list.
  - If it's a delete:

    - Add the id to your set.
- Create a new list to return as the result.
- For each item in the original list:

  - Check to see if it's in your set.

    - If it's in the set, skip it (it got deleted).
    - If not, append it to the result.
- Return the result.

Where N is the list size and K is the number of operations, this ends up being O(N+K), because you iterated over the entire list of IDs exactly twice, and the entire list of operations exactly once, and everything you did inside those iterations was O(1).

Comment: Note that if the problem required you to maintain a data structure where you could delete a single item from the middle in better than O(N) time, a Python list would straight up make it impossible; you'd want to use a doubly linked list or maybe an ordered dict.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I only get the id of one element, and I have to find out the id of the other one (it's the next one in the list), how can I do this efficently?

Comment: The dict gives you a O(1) way to find an index given an ID, and the list gives you a O(1) way to find an ID given an index.  Indices also have the useful property that you can just add one to find the next one.  Note that you have to deal with deletions, so you may need to iterate to find the next **non-deleted** item in the list.  If that turns out to be problematic you might need to take a look at building a linked list so you can actually remove items from the list in realtime.

Comment: Exactly that, thanks! I was thinking of checking if the item in list [n+1] is in the set, and if it is keep doing +1 until the value in that index isn't in the set, is this right?

Comment: yup, that's it exactly.  How efficient that'll be will depend on how many items get deleted before you do your swaps...